# How to read papers of professors?

Tags: soft-question

This is a question that has been in my mind for a month now. I am a final year M.Sc student in mathematics and applying for graduate school this year. But for applying to graduate schools, let's say in Europe, it is recommended that you should study the papers of Professors to whom you are applying. My question is how to go about reading the papers? I am interested in doing research in algebraic geometry and I have only taken a course in basic undergraduate algebraic geometry and some basic homological algebra. I should have done my M.Sc thesis in algebraic geometry but in my university, nobody is working on this topic. Also, I didn't know I am interested in algebraic geometry until the last year otherwise I would have done some internships on this topic. With this background, there is no way I could understand the papers of a Professor who is working on the subject for years. This is certainly not a problem in the US as you don't have to apply to a Professor, but in Europe, I think in most of the cases, you have to directly apply to a Professor. So, what to do in this case?

Thanks in advance!
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: My suggestion, email people you would be interested in working with, i did so, they can inform you a lot better on their selves, and ask people from your universitie about their opinions,  that is what i did!

Comment: @Enkidu But in my university there is no one to talk to as nobody is working in that area.

Comment: well somebody taught AG. also, it does not have to be your university, be bold go out there, ask people, send mails. People are usually quite nice